# aspxCallback is not working

Tags: asp.net, callback, devexpress

it is not executing the code event
actually nothing happens
i tried everything but of no use.
help :/

Aspxcallbackpanel is not working here is my code

script in aspx file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cse_btn_load_click() {
        cbp.PerformCallBack('p_btn_load_click');
    }
    function cse_btn_add_var_click() {
        cbp.PerformCallBack('p_btn_add_var_click');
    }
    function cse_btn_sendmsg_click() {
        cbp.PerformCallBack('p_btn_sendmsg_click');
    }
</script>
```

all buttons are like this

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="Add" AutoPostBack="false">
                                                                                        <ClientSideEvents Click="cse_btn_add_var_click" />
                                                                                           </dx:ASPxButton>
```

my aspx.cs file is

```
protected void ASPxCallbackPanel1_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {

        if (e.Parameter == "p_btn_load_click")
        {
            btn_load_Click(sender, e);
        }
        else if (e.Parameter == "p_btn_add_var_click")
        {
            ASPxButton1_Click(sender, e);
        }
        else if (e.Parameter == "p_btn_sendmsg_click")
        {
            btn_sendmsg_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is dx:ASPxButton? Is it some control library you are using other than the traditional asp.net controls?

Comment: @deostroll - `DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors`

Comment: do you get any javascript errors when you click on button?

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PerformCallback Instead of PerformCallBack

```
script type="text/javascript">
        function cse_btn_load_click() {
            cbp.PerformCallback('p_btn_load_click');
        }
        function cse_btn_add_var_click() {
            cbp.PerformCallback('p_btn_add_var_click');
        }
        function cse_btn_sendmsg_click() {
            cbp.PerformCallback('p_btn_sendmsg_click');
        }
    </script>
```